# Apache and PHP symlink behavior

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, symbolic-link

I have debian installed with apache2 and php and symlinks are working. But not as I expect:

```
/a/b/config.json
/a/b/index.php
/a/b/api/api.php

/var/www/html/x/config.json
/var/www/html/x/index.php -> /a/b/index.php
/var/www/html/x/api -> /a/b/api
/var/www/html/y -> /a/b
```

The code in `api.php` reads `../config.json`. But in both cases `/a/b/config.json` is used. Is it possible to configure the system so that `/var/www/html/x/config.json` is used for the first case and `/a/b/config.json` for the second case?

Comment: Your cases are swapped in the final question

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but a workaround!

I used this inside the php code to extract the path from where the scripts are called:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

Works great, cause `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` contains `/var/www/html/x/api/api.php` or `/var/www/html/y/api/api.php`, so I can build the relative path.

Backdraw: Every place that uses relative paths must be changed.

Comment: I don't think that this would work.

Comment: Why do you think it would not work? I tried it and it works cause `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` contains `/var/www/html/x` or `/var/www/html/y`.

Comment: Because the manual says it has the **Absolute Path** which may resolve the symlink.  However, if you have tried it then perhaps you should emphasize that point in your answer.  To me, **Works Great** doesn't tell the OP that you have tried in the same scenario.